# Alternative to pickle for javascript

Tags: javascript, python, tensorflow, pickle, tensorflow.js

I'm working on a deep learning project and I got stucked: I have a jupiter notebook that processes a dataset of images and returns a list of tensors in python, which I pickle with pickle.dump(). Before, I was unpickling the list in pyhon, and then using it to train my model, so I had no issues...
But now I need those pickled data loaded also in the browser (to be able to use them with tensorflow js).
Do you know any good alternative to pickle? Obviously I could save my data in a different format in python, so that after I'd be able to load them in js... I just don't know which format is the best (JSON?).

To be clearer on the type of data, this is my data before pickling/after unpickling it in python:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[[ 31.741358  36.196915  36.969135]
   [ 31.762732  40.762733  39.762733]
   [ 28.562115  38.562115  37.562115]
   ...
   [ 21.795372  27.795372  27.795372]
   [ 29.314323  33.314323  32.314323]
   [ 25.28419   29.28419   28.28419 ]]

  [[ 33.765278  39.765278  39.765278]
   [ 31.849304  40.849304  39.849304]
   [ 29.36111   39.36111   38.36111 ]
   ...
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Tensorflow.js describes how to load and save modules [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/save_load), using `.json` and `.weights.bin` files, and [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/conversion) you can find instructions on how to convert to and from other common formats using [`tensorflowjs_converter `](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-converter).

Comment: Thank you for answering but this is not my question! I don't need to save and convert my model, I just need an alternative to pickle for javascript!

Comment: Infact, I need to re-write and re-train my model from scratch in js, so I need the data  (I would like to skip the preprocessing of dataset in js, so I'm looking for a way to just get the final tensor in js, which I already have in python )

Comment: I don't know if I get it right. What I think is that saving the data in JSON with python will make it easier to load back that data in javaScript